# Re-populate a sequence of continuous ID variable by another ID variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Apologies for the vagueness of the title.

Hopefully the following example will make more sense.

```
have = data.frame(id = c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2"),
                  id2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3))
want = data.frame(id = c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2"),
                  id2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6))
```

How can I go from have to want by using dplyr package? I have over a million # of obs in my df in this structure.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks heaps!

Comment: What is exact condition of   **from `1~3` to `4~6` when `A1` to `A2`**?

Comment: Need some more details. Do you always have `id2`s in pairs? Can there be only one entry? Or three? What are the rules?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info. There is no specific pattern for id2. Rather than restarting from 1 for id2 whenever id changes, I want id2 to continue on with the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rleid` from `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

have %>% 
  mutate(id2 = rleid(id2))
```

**Output**

```
   id id2
1  A1   1
2  A1   1
3  A1   2
4  A1   2
5  A1   3
6  A1   3
7  A2   4
8  A2   4
9  A2   5
10 A2   5
11 A2   6
12 A2   6
```

Or just with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(have)[, id2 := rleid(id2)]
```

Or with `rle` from base R:

```
have$id2 <- with(rle(have$id2), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum` with a logical expression (`lead(id2) == id2`) to populate the sequence. This will add 1 to the `id2` column when `id2` column changes, so that the result would be a consecutive sequence.

```
library(dplyr)

want2 <- have %>% 
  mutate(id2 = cumsum(lead(id2) == id2)) %>% 
  fill(id2, .direction = "down")

want2
   id id2
1  A1   1
2  A1   1
3  A1   2
4  A1   2
5  A1   3
6  A1   3
7  A2   4
8  A2   4
9  A2   5
10 A2   5
11 A2   6
12 A2   6
```